# How to link the codes on Spree Github with the codes on Ruby on Rails spree ecommerce store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

sorry if this questions are too simple. Just started to learn Ruby on Rails and Spree ecommerce.

Successfully installed the demo store according the the instructions here: https://github.com/spree/spree , however, I don't quite understand how the source codes at the Github are linked to the sources codes on the Ruby on Rails spree ecommerce store. The directories are pretty different from each other. For example, spree source codes have "/API", "/backend", "/core", etc...  while the ruby on rails spree ecommerce store has "/app", "/bin", "/config", etc...

I know the ruby on rails auto generates some codes. But how the two correlated with each other? Say, some codes at Spree ecommerce are updated, what to do to update the Spree store?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more about how [Gem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html), [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) and [Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) works.

The Spree framework is a gem that works as an engine with each part(API, backend, frontend, core) separated in their own directories like a separated gem, just for better organization. Used to be all inside the Spree gem back in the day.

Your Rails app, the one with the 'app/', 'bin/' and 'config/' directories, is the true application, when you install/add Spree in your app it will be mounted alongside with your Rails app and will provide all the e-commerce platform.

In short when your add a gem into your Gemfile, the gem will be downloaded to your local system in the `bundle install` part. Rails will load the files from the gems listed on your Gemfile and everything will be good and accessible, automagically for you.

To update the gem spree you would have to use the `bundle update spree` command and the `bundler` will take care of updating the files.

To customize your Spree code, you can start to learn how in their [guide](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you for your insightful knowledge and sharing! I found the Engines (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) are quite helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful knowledge and sharing! I found the Engines (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) are quite helpful. Something still in my mind is, in the demo store directories, those directories where Spree is seen are: "/vendor", "/public/spree/products", "/db/migrate/", and some files in "/config". Is that all to be required for a spree ecommerce demo store? Or am I still missing some pieces? Cause I read "One difference here, however, is that each directory contains a sub-directory with the engine name." I don't see Spree subdirectory in "/app", or "/lib".

Comment: The Spree directories found on Github will not show for you inside your app, they are in their gems and load at the app startup from your system. All the directories you listed in your comment are required for Spree(demo store) and most of apps will use and have the same structure.

Comment: Thanks! Figured that out!